# Can't install imagick in PHP 8.0.13 with WAMP 3.2.6

Tags: php, imagemagick, wamp, imagick

I have a problem getting imagick to work in php 8.0.13 with wamp3.2.6. I have followed several, several tutorials but none seem to have worked.

My PHP version is 8.0.13
Architecture : x64
Thread Safety : Enable

For example i followed this tutorial: https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-windows-imagick.html and it doesn't work either.

However, with this imagick tutorial, it seems that Imagick is installed. When i do

```
phpinfo();
```

Here an Image :
[image]

So we see that Imagick seems to be installed.
But, if i try some PHP code like this:
[image]

or

[image]

nothing is displayed on my web page
[image]

Your help will be much appreciated!

Thanks a lot !
Pascal

Comment: Please add code as properly formatted text not images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score -1):

I fixed my issue...

This webpage is exactly what i did and all is now working

https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-windows-imagick.html

But also, i deleted all PATH containing ImageMagick of all version **because i don't use imagemagick**. I only use Imagick in PHP. Also, i added in PATH, the path of my PHP version

Hpe that helps